# ValueError: max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df for pipeline

Tags: python-3.x

Code =
Any ideas as to how to adjust the min/max so that i dont recieve the error message ' ValueError: max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df'

```
LogRegpipe = Pipeline([('cv', CountVectorizer(stop_words= stop_words)), ('lr', LogisticRegression(max_iter=300))])
LRparams = {'cv__max_df':[0.1,0.2,0.3],
               'cv__min_df':[5,10],
               'cv__max_features':[100,300],
               'cv__ngram_range':[(1,1),(1,2)],
               'lr__C':[0.001,0.01,0.1]}

logGS1 = GridSearchCV(LogRegpipe, param_grid = LRparams, cv = 5, n_jobs=-1, verbose = 1)
logGS1.fit(X_train, y_train)

class_report(logGS1, y_test, X_testbow)
```

Comment: your min_df  should be smaller than max_df ..,